# $ is undefined javascript errors with django templates

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

In my Django project I load jQuery, in addition to other scripts dependent on jQuery.  Some of the scripts are loaded as includes (text/html templates), since I use Django variables in them.  In my error log I frequently see $ is undefined errors, or Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function, and other similar errors.  This issue only occurs sporadically, so is very hard to reproduce and diagnose.  Any ideas?

loaded in base template (bottom of body):

```
<script src="/media/js/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

loaded in page templates:

```
{% include "javascript/example-script.js" %}
<script src="/media/js/admin.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should be sure to include all js scripst using jquery after jquery. I'm sorry i can not help you more as i don't know django. Maybe just load jquery from <head>

Comment: once the page is rendreed, do a view source - see the order in which the js files are loaded

Comment: If it is sporadic, perhaps it is only on certain events it is happening for. For example, I know as of jQuery 1.7 the .live() method is deprecated and should use.on() instead.

Comment: Errors occur sporadically on the exact same event.

Comment: Then like roasted suggested, I would put the call to load jquery in <head> rather than body. Perhaps you are overriding your content block on other pages which is causing problems? Hard to know without seeing more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure jQuery was actually loaded by typing `jQuery.fn.jquery;` into the console. If it returns a version number it's loaded, if not then you're not including it in the template correctly.

If it returns a version number then you may have something conflicting with the `$` variable. In that case, you can either use `jQuery` in place of it, or you can use [`noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).